# C++ library for creating, visualizing, and algorithmically manipulating data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, mesh

I am in need of some C++ library, that would allow me to create data structures like trees, mesha and etc.
Once the tree or mesh is created, i should be able to visualize it. And Once created I should be able to plugin my algorithm in the structure,
to perform various task such as finding the best possible path, and many others.

Is there an already available c++ library or do I have to go through the pain of creating a data structure myself?

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: There are many combinations of C and C++ libraries that do part of what you want. But for all that would something like Matlab be more appropriate then C or C++?

Comment: Also Python's main page has a whole section on this stuff:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting

Comment: I suggest looking at vtk, opencv and boost.

Comment: @DougT. The project i am working in doesn't allow me to use python or matlab. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: @drescherjm I would go through the libraries. But isn't vtk and opencv graphical libraries? I would really want to have some libraries that would allow me to create and manipulate mesh networks.

Comment: I thought you wanted to visualize these. These libraries create meshes and allow you manipulate (through code and / or the GUI) and to visualize in a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you mean by visualize. You generally need to use some GUI library for the visualization part. and for Data structures. STL, boost has the wide variety of Data structures that you will even need. There is heap, linked list, list structures in STL, thre is circular buffer in boost. you can easily play with them.

Comment: Boost has a great graph library too.

Comment: @Neel Basu Thanks for the reply bro, but aren't there any libraries that would allow me to create a mesh network and play with them??

Comment: there are many. but what you meant by Play ? If you want to play with structures then there is no problem. but if you want your Algorithm's simulation there are many Educational Java Applets That you can use to visualize. But if you want to make your own visualizer then you have to use some GUI Library